# Error while read in cassandra system.log

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Since the upgrade from Cassandra version 2.2.7 to 3.0.8 I'm getting following error almost every several minutes on every node. For node at 173.170.147.120 (the IP is fake, I replaced the real one) error in `system.log` would be:

```
INFO  [SharedPool-Worker-4] 2016-09-28 10:26:39,068 Message.java:605 
   - Unexpected exception during request; channel = [id: 0xfd64cd67,
   /173.170.147.120:50660 :> /18.4.63.191:9042]
java.io.IOException: Error while read(...): Connection reset by peer
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.readAddress(Native Method) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannel$EpollSocketUnsafe.doReadBytes(EpollSocketChannel.java:675) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannel$EpollSocketUnsafe.epollInReady(EpollSocketChannel.java:714) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:326) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:264) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
```

As far as I see, in all such errors there are always `[id: <...>, /<broadcast_address>:<some_port> :> /<listen_address>:<native_transport_port>`. Also `broadcast_address` and `listen_address` are always belong to the current node adresses.

Also, the problem occurs regardless of whether there are connected clients.

**What are possible reasons of such errors and how can I fix it?**

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

**UPD**. I thought, the issue can be related to old keyspace migration, but it reproduces even with only newly created KSs.

Comment: Did you solved the issue or got any idea about the scenario? I'm having the same scenario now a days. @allight

Comment: @AnowerPerves, no, I still having the issue. I also asked about it on mailing list (and I think I saw your question there recently). Maybe we should create a ticket -- seems like problem appears after upgrade 2.2.x -> 3.0.x.


P.S. Should say, I didn't find out any harm from it.

Comment: May be I'm near to the solve, If its solved, I'll let you know. @allight

Comment: @AnowerPerves thanks!

Comment: Anyone knows why this happens? I am seeing this too.

Comment: @SRHLABS, probably best decision here is to create a tiket to jira. Also, have you recently updated your cluster C* version?

Comment: Anyone know the reason for this ? plz update

Comment: @Knight71, I still don't know the reason, sorry